# Deleted libnl-3-200 by mistake

Tags: networking, network-manager

I was trying to fix a broken package (libnl-route-3-200) in Ubuntu 16.04. By mistake I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove libnl-3-200
```

And didn't realize the importance of Network Library. 
Now, my Ubuntu system can't connect to the network.
I get the message:

> The system network services are not compatible with this version Ubuntu.

How can I fix the system?

Comment: I didn't checked that. Though, I tried to fix the issue using recovery mode of ubuntu .. but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are still able to access the internet, from some other device.

My advice in such a case would be to go to https://packages.ubuntu.com and search for the desired package for the desired ubuntu version. In your case (assuming amd64) this leads to this [download link](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb).

Download the file, (optionally but recomended: verify the fingerprint) and copy it to your computer by some means (e.g. flash drive), Finally to install the package run

```
sudo dpkg -i libnl-3-200_3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

The package is now manually installed, but I assume as soon as an update is available it will be replaced by newer version from the repositories.

Comment: Hello mbeyss,Thanks for the help. I had to manually download all the deleted packages from ubuntu package manager. I downloaded around 60 packages. The list of packages which got deleted was available on ubuntu software center. How it came to 60? Because... with the deleted packages, the dependencies was also needed to be downloaded. Thereby, extensively working for 4hrs to download and installing. Well, making a mindmap for the packages was a great idea.

Comment: Hello mbeyss, I need one more help. Please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071687/need-help-to-fix-broken-packages-while-installing-shutter

Answer (score 1):

If `apt` removed that package, it would have also removed all packages that depend on it, which is a bigger issue.

First, I'd check `/var/log/apt/history.log` what actually got removed. There should be a section near the end of that file, with the date and time when you called apt, its command line and what packages were removed:

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

This format is a bit annoying to work with, so use:

```
$ sed -e 's/ ([^)]*)//g' -e 's/, / /g' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

This removes the version numbers and commas from the log file, for easier copy&paste.

For each of the packages listed in that block under `Remove:` or `Purge:`, add them to the command line of ①

```
# apt --print-uris install libnl-3-200
```

This will give you a list of URLs to download. Process this list by appending

```
| sed -ne "/http/s/'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p"
```

to remove the quotes around the URLs and the file name and checksum, and redirect this into a file. The full command line should look similar to

```
# apt --print-uris install libnl-3-200 | sed -ne "/http/s/'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" >urls.txt
```

but with a bunch more packages.

Copy that file onto an USB stick, go to another machine and download these files, e.g. using `wget`:

```
$ wget -i urls.txt
```

Take the USB stick back to the original machine, copy the `.deb` files to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`:

```
# cp *.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Then, install by running apt as before under ①, but without the `--print-uris` option. It should pick up the files from the cache directory and install them.

Comment: Hello Simon, thanks for replying. I was able run the network by manually installing all the packages with carefully managing the dependencies. Now, I am having another issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071687/need-help-to-fix-broken-packages-while-installing-shutter